# I always get a value of 255 characters

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my Postgres DB. In this table, there is a column `city` this column has type `character` and length 255.

When I try to add a city in this column, for example, London and after that, I try to get this city I get a value with 255 lengths.

Looks likes [London....................-255] where dots are empty characters

When I add value in db always doing `trim`.

I use **pg** for node js

Comment: That's how the `char` data type is supposed to work. The simple solution is: [don't use the char type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: try to add data using insert statement and check what exactly is getting added ?

Comment: is there any default value added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, [you don't want to use `character(255)`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) as the field type, which is always 255 characters, padded with whitespace.

Instead, you might consider using `varchar(255)`, but even so, [you probably don't actually want to limit the length here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_varchar.28n.29_by_default) – Postgres doesn't care, storage-wise!, whereas MySQL does – so just use `text`.